# Move error in for-loop when not reborrowing a mutable slice

Tags: vector, rust

I'm trying to pass a mutable slice to a function and use it in several loops inside it.

`function1` produces an error. Changing to `function2` or `function3` makes the errors disappear, but I don't understand the differences between `function1` and `function2`. `v` and `&mut *v` seem similar to me.

Why doesn't `function1` work while the others do?

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = Vec::new();

    function1(&mut v);
    function2(&mut v);
    function3(&mut v);
}

// Move Error 
fn function1(v: &mut [i32]) {
    for l in v {}
    for l in v {} // <-- Error Here !!!
}

// Works Fine
fn function2(v: &mut [i32]) {
    for l in &mut *v {}
    for l in &mut *v {}
}

// Works Fine
fn function3(v: &mut [i32]) {
    for l in v.iter_mut() {}
    for l in v.iter_mut() {}
}
```

The error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `v`
  --> src/main.rs:12:14
   |
11 |     for l in v {}
   |              - value moved here
12 |     for l in v {} // <-- Error Here !!!
   |              ^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `v` has type `&mut [i32]`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Comment: Hi! Your post had two minor questions: 1. your example was not minimal and 2. your asked two different questions. I tried to fix both issues by editing your post to avoid you being downvoted (your actual question is really good). If you think I changed too much or you disagree with the edit for another reason, just roll it back!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&mut *v` is doing a so-called "reborrow".

This means that instead of iterating over the original reference, you are iterating over a new reference.

Think about it this way:

---

If you have an *owned* vector, and you iterate over it, then you get the same error if you try iterating over it again, because it has been moved into the for loop.

If instead you borrow the vector and iterate over the borrow, then you can do that as many times as you want.

---

If you have a mutable borrow, and you iterate over it, then you are moving the mutable borrow into the for loop. So it's gone now.

If instead you create a new reference pointing into the mutable borrow, you are just moving out of the new reference. Once the iteration finishes, the new mutable borrow is gone, meaning that the original mutable borrow can be accessed again.

Comment: Also. `for i in v { ... }` desugars to `let mut iter = v.into_iter(); while let Some(i) = iter.next { ... }`. `into_iter` consumes `v`, `(&mut *v).into_iter()` consumes freshly created reference.